# reading excel file using XMLStreamReader ( read number as string, not as a number )

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xmlreader

I am reading an excel file using XMLStreamReader object. The initialization of this object is somewhat like this :

```
opcPkg = OPCPackage.open(excelPath, PackageAccess.READ);
xssfReader = new XSSFReader(opcPkg);
factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
iterator = xssfReader.getSheetsData();
inputStream = iterator.next();
xmlReader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
```

The contents of a cell are read using this statement,

```
xmlReader.getElementText();
```

The problem is that a simple number string 10.2 contained in a cell is being read as 10.199999999999999. I want it to be read as 10.2 only. Is there a way to solve this ?

Comment: Did you try using [DataFormatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html)? If not, what happens when you do?

Answer (score 0):

When you read it as a String, do you parse it with

```
Double.parseDouble(...getText() );
```

That would be the surest way to get a number out of a line of text